# Assignment to the array of Structures

Tags: c++, c, unix

i have an array of structure.And what i want to do is to assign values to the members of those structures.what is the problem in the following code...

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct{
int a1;
int a2;

}sample;


main(){

sample ar[4]={ 
    (1,2),
    (3,4),
    (5,6),
    (7,8) 
};

int i;
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf("ar[%d]----%d  %d",i,ar[i].a1,ar[i].a2);
     }
}
```

Now it is being compiled successfully.but the output is

```
ar[0]----2  4 
ar[1]----6  8 
ar[2]----0  0 
ar[3]----0  0
```

instead of (or may be the program is doing right and i am suffering from a silly misconception)

```
ar[0]----1  2
ar[1]----3  4 
ar[2]----5  6 
ar[3]----7  8
```

Comment: after rectification provided in answers you will get correct result. show your complete code for new question. Yes add **\n** in printf for new line

Comment: ok.second bracket(e.g {....}  ) should be used everywhere in assignment.i was using the first bracket(e.g (....)  ) then

Comment: kernef maniac good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written:

```
sample ar[4];
ar[4] = { 
    (1,2),
    (3,4),
    (5,6),
    (7,8) 
};
```

The syntax of the *array initializer* (only valid during the *initialization* of `ar`) is:

```
sample ar[4] = { 
    {1,2},
    {3,4},
    {5,6},
    {7,8} 
};
```

> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.7.9 Initialization
>
> ```
> initializer:   
>     assignment-expression 
>     { initializer-list } 
>     { initializer-list , }
> ```

Also, [*indentation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) is important to write readable code.

Comment: yes the assignment worked.but the output of the printf statement is wrong.i will edit my post

Comment: @kernelmaniac: I've tested it on my computer, it seems to work. What do you expect, and what do you get?

Comment: what i expected is specified in my edit.please see it.may be i am suffering from a silly misconception

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize your vector this way:

```
sample ar[4] = {
    {1,2},
    {3,4},
    {5,6},
    {7,8}
};
```

Also, you should specify the return type of `main()`:

```
       int main()
    // ^^^
    // ...
```

Comment: Not true, it may be an implicit declaration.

Comment: @xavier: What do you mean?

Comment: I should have said - implicit type. Without the explicit return type, function defaults to int. In some of the C standards, at least.

Comment: Implicit declaration means that the compiler doesn't know about the function but trusts you that it exists and you know how to use it. `-Werror` makes implicit declarations errors instead of a warnings.

Comment: @xavier: Not in C++ though. It is true that the question is tagged both as C and as C++. I will edit the answer to clarify this

Comment: @DavidCzihak: Xavier meant something different (something which is probably possible in C - I don't know - but not in C++)

Comment: The valid definition of `main` is `int main()` both in C as well as C++.Functions without return types used to default to `int` but that was way back in c89 not anymore.

Comment: @AlokSave: Thank you for clarifying. I will restore the original wording then.

Comment: At least it's good practice to use `int main(int argc, char** argv)` as this header is present on most platforms and C compilers.

Comment: @DavidCzihak: But `int main()` is equally valid

Comment: And so is `void main(void)` on most platforms.

Comment: @DavidCzihak: I don't know about C, but definitely that's not Standard C++.

Comment: True, I have missed the C++ tag. But when we speak about C - for a short snippet of code nobody really cares about being compliant with a specific standard, right? And implicit return type is **not** reported by default by gcc.

Comment: @xavier: Honestly, I believe you always have to care. Even for small things like this one, at least just to keep a good habit. Unless I am *forced* to do this (e.g. I have to write non-portable code by using well-documented compiler extensions because my company is using that product and I have to be compliant with the company's conventions), every single bit of code I write must be compliant with the C++ Standard.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the assignment with the declaration and always use "{".

```
sample ar[4] = { 
    {1,2},
    {3,4},
    {5,6},
    {7,8} 
};
```